# Undefined error in java

Tags: compiler-errors, undefined

```
public class Officepersonel extends Personel {

 int workidno;String name,surname;
public Officepersonel(String name,String surname, int kimlikno, final int workidno)
{
    super(name,surname,kimlikno,workidno);
}

private void showcard(final int workidno)
{
    System.out.println("Nameim, "+name+"Surnameim "+surname+": Kartimi okutuyorum.");
}

@Override
public void goWorkCome( int workidno)
{

    super.goWorkCome( workidno);
    showcard(workidno);


}
```

}

```
public class Personel extends Insan {

 String name,surname;   int workidno;

public Personel(String name,String surname, int kimlikno,final int workidno)
{
    super(name,surname,kimlikno);


}




public void goWorkCome( int workidno)
{

    System.out.println("Nameim, "+name+"Surnameim "+surname+": Ise gidiyorum.\nIsten geliyorum");

}
```

Hello. I am getting errors in this code.

The method goworkcome(int) of type officePersonel must override or implement a supertype 
     method it says. i am already overriding.

And The method showcard(int) is undefined for the type 
    officvePersonel

These classes are in different pages so no problem about which one is first.

Answer (score 0):

Add or Change your jre to javaJRE-1.6

Eclipse -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> add library ....

this may work!

Comment: above code is ok in my eclipse IDE.(i drop Insan class).
and almost is the eclipse problem.
you can restart your IDE,or change jre,or look at Insan class.